# how to draw a Google Pie Chart only on a click event using javascript/jquery?

Tags: jquery, onclick, google-visualization

how to draw a Google Pie Chart only on a click event using javascript/jquery?
Ive tried calling drawChart on an onclick event with no success.

From the api:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     11],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ['Commute',  2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep',    7]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just realized - maybe you ask because you simply have forgotten to include jquery? :-) eg something like `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>` - and thats why your attempts didnt work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To extend davidkonrad's answer, you should wrap the click event in the callback from the API loader, as it is plausible that a user with a slow connection to Google's servers could click the draw button before the API is finished loading:

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
        ['Work',     11],
        ['Eat',      2],
        ['Commute',  2],
        ['Watch TV', 2],
        ['Sleep',    7]
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'My Daily Activities'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
function initialize () {
    $(/* click event element selector */).click(function() {
        drawChart();
    });
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
```

Comment: I was doing this, but i discovered why it wasnt working. The div for the chart was in a template which itself was only being shown on a click event. The div didnt exist until after that event, so the javascript couldnt find it.

Answer (score 6):

Just wrap the call to `drawchart` into a click handler instead of `OnLoadCallback` :

```
  $('html, body').click(function() {
    drawChart();
  });
```

Whole script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     11],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ['Commute',  2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep',    7]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }

      $('html, body').click(function() {
        drawChart();
      });

    </script>
```